# Deleting a record from Event object

Tags: event, crud

I have an app that is used to delete an event using the event ID, and it seems to be working, however I noticed after deleting the event, there are still records in `EventRelation` where the `EventId` is the event I just deleted. Is the app also responsible for deleting those records as well? To be clear, the app didn't create the `EventRelation` records.

Comment: Which app are you using? Before you delete the Event, can you also find out the EventRelation associated with them and check which object it refers to?

Comment: @sanketkumar It's a node app i've written sorry that wasn't clear. I can find the EventRelations myself but I'm asking, should I? Because when I delete the record in salesforce itself, it doesn't seem to cleanup the related EventRelations either. So my instincts tell me to leave it alone to mimic the behavior in salesforce.

Comment: odd, Event -> EventRelation is `cascadeDelete = true`

Comment: @cropredy So what you're saying is, they should get automatically cleaned up when events are deleted. So sounds like the org has `cascadeDelete` disabled in this instance?

Comment: cascadeDelete on OOTB relations can't be customized - my 'odd' remark was that I'm surprised you are getting this behavior